# Inconsistent Predicted Class Assignments for Same Probability in Binary Classification Model

Tags: r, binary, knn, tidymodels

I'm working on a binary classification problem, and I've encountered a situation where the predicted class assignments seem inconsistent for observations with the same predicted probability of 0.5. The model provides different .pred_class values (0 or 1) for these cases. I'm trying to understand why this happens and how to interpret it. Here's an example of my data:

| id | .pred_class | .row | neighbors | weight_func | .pred_0 | .pred_1 | Target | .config |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Slice1 | 0 | 263 | 12 | rectangular | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0 | Preproc… |
| Slice3 | 0 | 413 | 12 | rectangular | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0 | Preproc… |
| Slice3 | 0 | 415 | 12 | rectangular | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0 | Preproc… |
| Slice3 | 0 | 416 | 12 | rectangular | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1 | Preproc… |
| Slice3 | 1 | 417 | 12 | rectangular | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1 | Preproc… |
| Slice5 | 1 | 480 | 12 | rectangular | 0.5 | 0.5 | 1 | Preproc… |

Can someone help me understand why the .pred_class values are different for the same predicted probability of 0.5? What factors could influence this, and how should I interpret these predictions? Are there any common practices for handling such cases?

Comment: look at your table the predictions are given with 1 decimal precision, which isnt a lot; I would investigate that its not simply a case of .pred_1 being 0.49 ; being shown to you as 0.5 and mapped to 0, and other times being 0.504 , shown to you as 0.5 and mapping to 1

Comment: the probabilities are the outcome of tune_grid and they have the full number of digits; In above example you see the outcome of filter(.pred_1 == 0.5), so 0.5 == 0.5

Comment: The issue arises only when using the 'rectangular' weight function. The other available hyperparameter options include:  'triangular', 'epanechnikov', 'biweight', 'triweight', 'cosine', 'inv', 'gaussian'.